# Check if column contains (/,-,_, *or~) and split in another column - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, character, geopandas

I have a column with numbers and one of these characters between them -,/,*,~,_. I need to check if values contain any of the characters, then split the value in another column. Is there a different solution than shown below? In the end, columns subnumber1, subnumber2 ...subnumber5 will be merged in one column and column "number5" will be without characters. Those two columns I need to use in further process. I'm a newbie in Python so any advice is welcome.

```
if gdf['column_name'].str.contains('~').any():
    gdf[['number1', 'subnumber1']] = gdf['column_name'].str.split('~', expand=True)
gdf
if gdf['column_name'].str.contains('^').any():
    gdf[['number2', 'subnumber2']] = gdf['column_name'].str.split('^', expand=True)
gdf
Input column:
column_name  
152/6*3
163/1-6
145/1
163/6^3

output:
 number5 |subnumber1 |subnumber2
152      | 6         |  3
163      | 1         |  6
145      | 1         |
163      | 6         |  3
```

Comment: Please provide an explicit input/output example

Comment: The question is updated. @mozway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with list of possible separators and create new DataFrame:

```
import re

L = ['-','/','*','~','_','^', '.']

#some values like `^.` are escape
pat = '|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in L)
df = df['column_name'].str.split(pat, expand=True).add_prefix('num')
print (df)
  num0 num1  num2
0  152    6     3
1  163    1     6
2  145    1  None
3  163    6     3
```

EDIT: If need match values before value use:

```
L = ["\-_",'\^|\*','~','/']

for val in L:
    df[f'before {val}'] = df['column_name'].str.extract(rf'(\d+){[val]}')

#for last value not exist separator, so match $ for end of string
df['last'] = df['column_name'].str.extract(rf'(\d+)$')
print (df)
   column_name before \-_ before \^|\* before ~ before / last
0  152/2~3_4*5          3            4        2      152    5
1  152/2~3-4^5          4            4        2      152    5
2      152/6*3        NaN            6      NaN      152    3
3      163/1-6        NaN          NaN      NaN      163    6
4        145/1        NaN          NaN      NaN      145    1
5      163/6^3          6            6      NaN      163    3
```

Comment: What would be the case if I want to group by characters: first (*, ^) second (-, _), third (~) and fourth(/) ? @jezrael  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Ki-code - What means `group` ? How should be changed data in question in ouput with this requirement?

Comment: The output would have 5 columns. For example 152/2~3_4*5 and case 152/2~3-4^5. Values in columns would be: 152 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5. @jezrael

Comment: L = ['-|_','^|*','~','/'] Something like this but it don't work. @jezrael

Comment: @Ki-code - Not sure about logic . If there is list of separators then need number before separator? If there is - and _ in one line what is ouput?

Comment: It's "-" or "_" and "*" or "^" never both. I need the number after the character and I have two cases (152/2~3_4*5 and case 152/2~3-4^5). First split after *,^ and put in one column, then after -, _ and put numbers in the second column. Next is the number before "~", and then "/".

Comment: @Ki-code - I got it, I am look for solution

Comment: @Ki-code - for last values there is no parameter after them, so how extract it?

Comment: I thought that the last number can be a result of the Series.str.split method as in the example above.

Comment: @Ki-code - answer was edited

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df['column_name'].str.split(r'[*,-/^_]', expand=True)
```

output:

```
     0  1     2
0  152  6     3
1  163  1     6
2  145  1  None
3  163  6     3
```

Or, if you know in advance that you have 3 numbers, use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and named capturing groups:

```
regex = '(?P<number5>\d+)\D*(?P<subnumber1>\d*)\D*(?P<subnumber2>\d*)'
df['column_name'].str.extract(regex)
```

output:

```
  number5 subnumber1 subnumber2
0     152          6          3
1     163          1          6
2     145          1           
3     163          6          3
```

Comment: same like my answer

Comment: Oh you just changed, this was with a loop before

Comment: yes, after edited question also edited answer.

Comment: Anyway, it's not exactly the same, you use a `|` based regex, I use characters group